# Implement ng2-charts in an Angular-Seed

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts, angular-seed

I was unable to to compile a Production AOT build ("npm run build.prod.rollup.aot") in [Angular Seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) - after implementing [ng2-charts](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts) in my app (when I run "npm run start.deving - I could've seen the chart, but it would fail for Karma UnitTesting - in the ***.spec.ts file).

Answer (score 0):

The following solution did the work for me (**after installing ng2-chart & charts.js via npm**):

import **ChartsModule** in your main module (e.g. "home.module.ts"):

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
```

Then - provide it to let other components (that are inside this module) use this module (do the same in your equivalent "...spec.ts" file (e.g. "home.component.spec.ts"):

```
@NgModule({
imports:[ChartsModule,...]
)}
```

- Fix Karma UnitTesting & AOT compilation by amending the following to your **project.config.ts**

--

```
this.ROLLUP_NAMED_EXPORTS = [
  ...this.ROLLUP_NAMED_EXPORTS,
  {'node_modules/ng2-charts/ng2-charts.js': ['ChartsModule']}
]

let additionalPackages: ExtendPackages[] = [

  // required for dev build 
  {
    name: 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts',
    // Path to the package's bundle
    path: 'node_modules/ng2-charts/bundles/ng2-charts.umd.min.js'
  },
```

Just to make sure, I've added the actual chart implementation component (e.g. "line-chart.component.ts"):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'line-chart',
  templateUrl: './line-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['line-chart.component.css'],
})
export class LineChartComponent {
  // lineChart
  public lineChartData:Array<any> = [
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 110, 27, 120, 28, 48, 40, 19, 110, 27, 60, 120, 28, 48, 40, 19, 110, 27, 120, 28, 48, 40, 19, 110, 27, 60, 120], label: ''}
  ];
  public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
  public lineChartOptions:any = {
    scales: { // remove grid lines
      xAxes: [{
          display: false,
          gridLines: {
              display:false
          }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
          display: false,
          gridLines: {
              display:false
          }
      }]
    },    
    responsive: true,
    legend: {display:false}
  };
  public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
    {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      borderColor: '#9C0100',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#7E0001',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }
  ];
  public lineChartLegend:boolean = true;
  public lineChartType:string = 'line';

  public randomize():void {
    let _lineChartData:Array<any> = new Array(this.lineChartData.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.lineChartData.length; i++) {
      _lineChartData[i] = {data: new Array(this.lineChartData[i].data.length), label: this.lineChartData[i].label};
      for (let j = 0; j < this.lineChartData[i].data.length; j++) {
        _lineChartData[i].data[j] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      }
    }
    this.lineChartData = _lineChartData;
  }

  // events
  public chartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

and use it in each component (that is part of the module):

```
<line-chart></line-chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using ng2-charts in my Angular 6.1 website; however, I am using chart.js by itself in [mgechev/angular-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed).  I decided I don't need or want the extra ng2-charts wrapper.  In the end, you're really just using chart.js anyway.

As of writing this response, Chart.js developers [have some work to do](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5179) to make exporting its members compliant with newer standards.

To get Chart.js to work, all you need to do is:

1. Update `project.config.ts` to include ROLLUP_NAMED_EXPORTS

   > ```
   > this.ROLLUP_NAMED_EXPORTS = [
   >   ...this.ROLLUP_NAMED_EXPORTS,
   >   { 'node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js': ['Chart'] }
   > ];
   > ```
2. Update `project.config.ts` to include additional packages

   > ```
   > // Add packages
   > const additionalPackages: ExtendPackages[] = [
   >  { name: 'chart.js', path: 'node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js' },
   >
   >   ...
   >
   > ];
   > ```
3. In your component

   > ```
   > import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
   >
   > ...
   >
   > export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   >
   > @ViewChild('myChart') myChartRef: ElementRef;
   > chartObj: Chart;
   >
   > ...
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > Then load chart configuration in ngOnInit() per [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)
4. HTML will look something like this:

   > ```
   > <div class="chart-container">
   >    <canvas #myChart></canvas>
   > </div>
   > ```